# combining ssh and scp command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

Is there any way I can combine the following commands into one command? I do not want to login in each time for each command.

```
sshpass -p 'somepwd' ssh user@server "mkdir -p /home/user/test"
sshpass -p 'somepwd' scp file.sh user@server:/home/user/test
sshpass -p 'somepwd' scp /test/somefile.txt user@server:/home/user/test
sshpass -p 'somepwd' ssh user@server -C "cd /home/user/test;./file.sh"
```

I did check the answer for [combing multiple commands when using ssh and scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253599/combing-multiple-commands-when-using-ssh-and-scp); Based on that I would still need 3 logins, one for first ssh and mkdir, one for scp and one for ssh and running the shell script.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried key based authentication method for `ssh` ? If not, try searching `ssh-keygen` or do a `man ssh-keygen`.

Comment: You can use `rsync` to copy multiple files, and it will automatically create directories as needed. So that allows you to combine the first 3 commands.

Comment: `ControlMaster` is your friend -- you can have a single connection used for multiple commands.

Comment: (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing for an intro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `tar` and `ssh`:

```
tar -c file.sh test/somefile.txt | sshpass -p 'somepwd' ssh user@server -C "tar -C / --transform 's|test/||;s|^|/home/user/test/|' --show-transformed-names -xv; cd /home/user/test; ./file.sh"
```

For more secure methods to pass the password with `sshpass`, see `man sshpass`.

Comment: Nice use of `tar`! How is authentication accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Use public/private keys](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/) instead of password authentication. Not only will this simplify the use of `ssh`, it is much more secure, especially after you [disallow password authentication on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898942/553865) you are connecting to. Using password authentication means you *will* get hacked, or your server has already been compromised and you don't know it yet. The rest of this answer assumes you have set up public/private keys.
2. I see you have files in `/test`. Don't put your work in the root directory, this invites security issues. Instead, work in your home directory unless you are experienced with setting up permissions properly.
3. Because `file.sh` is in your current directory (whatever that is) and you want a file from `/test/` you cannot use `rsync`. `rsync` would be a good choice if all your files lived in the same directory.

Here is what we are left with; I have not messed with the location of `/test/` because I don't know enough about the task:

```
ssh user@server "mkdir -p /home/user/test"
scp file.sh user@server:/home/user/test
scp /test/somefile.txt user@server:/home/user/test
ssh user@server -C "cd /home/user/test;./file.sh"
```

Comment: The only thing I miss on this answer is the `ControlMaster`.